# Can't bind value to table in database php

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I keep trying this code below but for some reason it will not put the value in the database. The table in the database is named 'all'. I get no errors when running the script either.

```
$user = '0';
$bet = '0';

try
{
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='. $host .';dbname='.$db_name_wd, $db_username, $db_password);

  if($pdo){
    echo 'works';
  }
  $query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO all (w_id,w_amt) VALUES (?,?)'); 

  if($query){
    echo' works2 ';
  }
  $query->bindValue(1, $user);
  $query->bindValue(2, $bet);
  $query->execute();
  //echo $user;
  echo $user;
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
  exit('Error Connecting To DataBase');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add ` to your code, because `all` is a reserved word in mysql

> ```
> $query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO `all` (`w_id`,`w_amt`) VALUES (?,?)');
> ```

And on a side note, if you separated your PDO connection and query, you would have received an SQL syntax error.
Try having seperate functions for PDO connection and querying.

Comment: I did that and still nothing. I even tried a new table called w_all and still nothing.